# Publish asp.net core web app on smarterasp.net - exe files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to publish the sample web application in Visual Studio on smarterasp.net, but I can't complete the publish process beacause smarterasp doesn't allow to load exe files with the free account. However it seems that asp.net core is allowed with every type of account.

Have someone ever had the same problem? Do you know if it's possible to deploy an asp.net core application without exe files?